# exception occur when i get the LocationManager.(Android)

Tags: android, locationmanager

I want to get the Android mobile location. So I need to get the `LocationManager`, but Exception occurs and I don't know why. Can you help me? Below is my code.

```
public static String getMobileLocation(Context context) {
    LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    if (null == lm) {
        return "error01";
    }
    lm.setTestProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, true);
    lm.setTestProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, true);

    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
    criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
    criteria.setAltitudeRequired(false);
    criteria.setBearingRequired(false);
    criteria.setCostAllowed(true);
    criteria.setPowerRequirement(Criteria.POWER_LOW);
    String provider = lm.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
    if (provider == null || provider.length() == 0) {
        return "error02";
    }

    LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status,
                Bundle extras) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            LocationInfo.location = location;
        }
    };

    lm.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 0, 0, locationListener);

    while (null == location) {
        location = lm.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
    }
    if (null == location) {
        return "error03";
    }
    StringBuilder strBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    strBuilder.append(location.getLatitude());
    strBuilder.append(",");
    strBuilder.append(location.getLongitude());
    String str = strBuilder.toString();
    str = str.trim();
    if (null == str || str.length() == 0) {
        return "error04";
    }

    lm.removeUpdates(locationListener);
    lm.setTestProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, false);
    lm.setTestProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, false);
    location = null;

    return str;
}
```

Exception occur when I get the `LocationManager`.
DDMS log is here.
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Provider "gps" unknown
    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1331)
    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1281)
    at android.location.ILocationManager$Stub$Proxy.setTestProviderEnabled(ILocationManager.java:1122)
    at android.location.LocationManager.setTestProviderEnabled(LocationManager.java:1140)
    at ***.record.LocationInfo.getMobileLocation(LocationInfo.java:35)
    at** .MainActivity.initLocation(MainActivity.java:45)
    at **.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:40)

Comment: What is the exception ? It is probably a permission exception because you need to add the correct permissions in your manifest. Otherwise we really need to know your exception or post your DDMS log.'

Comment: ok,I will add the log when I get to the company tomorrow.thanks.

Comment: I added answer, it should fix

Answer (score 2):

**Update:**

`LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER` does not work for `setTestProviderEnabled()`

It seems to be depreceted of some sort.

Use:

```
locationManager.setTestProviderLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, location);
```

Comment: work if change LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER to just "test" everything, except new Location(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)